# drawing over an Image in HTML5 Canvas while preserving the image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

In HTML5 Canvas, what's the simplest way to draw *and move* a line over an Image (already on the canvas), preserving the image underneath?  (e.g. have a vertical line track the mouse X position)

My current canvas:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function() { 
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0,0);  
  }
  imageObj.src = "http://example.com/some_image.png";
  $('#myCanvas').click(doSomething);
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will have to do most of the ground-work with canvas which in this case you will have to implement the functionality to move the line and then redraw everything.

The steps can be:

- Keep the line as an object which can self-render (method on the object)
- Listen to mousemove (in this case) in order to move the line
- For each move, redraw background (image) then render the line at its new position

You can redraw the background as a whole or you can optimize it to just draw over the last line.

Here is some example code of this and a **[live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/5a2LR/)**:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('demo'), /// canvas element
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),            /// context
    line = new Line(ctx),                     /// our custom line object
    img = new Image;                          /// the image for bg

ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';                     /// white line for demo

/// start image loading, when done draw and setup 
img.onload = start;
img.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/O712qpO.jpg';

function start() {
    /// initial draw of image
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, demo.width, demo.height);

    /// listen to mouse move (or use jQuery on('mousemove') instead)
    canvas.onmousemove = updateLine;
}
```

Now all we need to do is to have a mechnism to update the background and the line for each move:

```
/// updates the line on each mouse move    
function updateLine(e) {

    /// correct mouse position so it's relative to canvas
    var r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = e.clientX - r.left,
        y = e.clientY - r.top;

    /// draw background image to clear previous line
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    /// update line object and draw it
    line.x1 = x;
    line.y1 = 0;
    line.x2 = x;
    line.y2 = canvas.height;
    line.draw();
}
```

The custom line object is in this demo very simple:

```
/// This lets us define a custom line object which self-draws
function Line(ctx) {

    var me = this;

    this.x1 = 0;
    this.x2 = 0;
    this.y1 = 0;
    this.y2 = 0;

    /// call this method to update line        
    this.draw = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(me.x1, me.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(me.x2, me.y2);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```

If you are not gonna do anything specific with the image itself you can also set it as a background-image using CSS. You will still need to clear the canvas before redrawing the line though.

Comment: live demo is offline

Answer (score 5):

May this is not an actual answer, just in case you need it (in the future). Working with canvas would be better (and easier) with some library. I have tried EaselJS of CreateJS and find myself loving it.
You can have a look at it [EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS)
(I have done an example allow drawing and dragging image using EaselJS long time before)

Answer (score 3):

You can get your "crosshairs" by listening to mousemove events and then:

- clear the canvas
- draw the image
- draw your line at the mouse position

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/jEc7N/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth=2;

    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        canvas.width=img.width;
        canvas.height=img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/KoolAidMan.png";

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(mouseX,0);
      ctx.lineTo(mouseX,canvas.height);
      ctx.moveTo(0,mouseY);
      ctx.lineTo(canvas.width,mouseY);
      ctx.stroke();


    }

    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

or just use **2 layers**:

1. background layer has image and do not change,
2. top layer has line, what you can clear and redraw it lots of time without affecting background layer.